# Expression result unused for gamecenter

Tags: iphone, expression, game-center

```
    static GCHelper *sharedHelper =nil;
    + (GCHelper *) sharedInstance
    {
         @synchronized ([GCHelper class])
    {
            If (!shareHelper)
    {
            [[self alloc] init];
    }
       return nil;
    }
```

I have it to run gamecenter but it gives me an error of "expression result unused" how do i fix this

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually assigning the result of `[[self alloc] init]` to `shareHelper`, which you almost certainly mean to do. This warning is pointing out your mistake.

Comment: It is not lettimg me archive  it because of that error how will i fix this

Comment: Do i just need to delete the line with [[self alloc]init]

Comment: Assign it. `shareHelper = [[self alloc] init];`  But the above code doesn't even work. It always returns `nil`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like for proper ways to implement this method.